# How to map nested routes to sub-classes in Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am using Mojolicious and will be building services at:

```
/admin/users/view/1
/admin/posts/view/1 
/admin/comments/view/1
```

How do I create the routes so that the controller matches 'admin/users' and translates that to Admin::Users

I want to achieve:

```
my $r = $self->routes;
$r->get('/*controller/:action/:id');
```

There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this without having to write a route for every admin controller, which seems like a waste.  The above statement yields a controller of 'Admin/posts' instead of 'Admin::Posts'

Can anyone shed some light on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found it.

```
$r->get('/admin/:controller/:action/:id')->to(namespace=>'MyApp::Admin);
```